# Django 1.6.5 - Streaming Media Images strategies

Tags: python, django, streaming, media

We have a WYSIWYG editor what enables users to upload images via drag/drop or manual upload.  As per standard Django practices, we save the image files from request.FILES to settings.MEDIA_ROOT, and the path in an ImageField.

The contents of whatever the user added in the editor are chunked into pieces, and stored as such, for streaming purposes during reading by other users, which is done as an AJAX get request at the time the user scrolls via mouse, etc.

The problem arrises when we attempt to show a chunk that has a large image.  The image isn't being shown to the readers.  If you refresh the page, the image is shown.  Leading me to believe it's a browser caching problem.

I am hoping to get feedback on the following idea to resolve this issue:

```
1) Store the image as a blob (BinaryField) in Django 1.6+
2) Calculate screen size of laptop/tablet and size the image blob in the view prior to returning it to the browser
3) Cache the Blob for N days for better performance
```